# having a small issue just displaying an image with C++ and GLADE

Tags: c++, glade

I know I am missing something really simple here, but all I am trying to do is display a image from a jpg file on a glade form statically w/o a file chooser,  here is my code so far, any help would be great.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *w_dlg_file_choose;       // Pointer to file chooser dialog box
    GtkWidget *w_img_main;              // Pointer to image widget
    GtkWidget      *image;
} app_widgets;

gchar *file_name = "image1.jpg";        // Name of file to open from dialog box
// image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("splash1.jpg");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder      *builder;
    GtkWidget       *window;

    app_widgets     *widgets = g_slice_new(app_widgets);
    // gchar *file_name = "file.jpg";        // Name of file to open 
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("splash1.jpg");
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("glade/window_main.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    widgets->w_dlg_file_choose = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dlg_file_choose"));
    widgets->w_img_main = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "img_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, widgets);
    //image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("myfile.png");
    // gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(app_wdgts->w_img_main), file_name);
    g_object_unref(builder);
    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();
    g_slice_free(app_widgets, widgets);
    return 0;
}
//////////- GUI Button-Signals-"no dragons here" - ///////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Event hanlders. Must be extern "C"

// File --> Open
void on_info_btn_clicked() {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy() {
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Please [edit] your question and add more information. What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Comment: ok so when the Glade form opens image1.jpg  should be shown on the Glade Form , it pretty explanatory from the description i think ,   I am trying to do is display a image from a jpg file on a glade form statically w/o a file chooser. but its not working